# Is there a way to know if a user taps on a WKInterfaceMap?

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

On WatchKit, the Map component is a `WKInterfaceMap` object.

This UI component by default, loads the main Map app on the Apple Watch when the user taps on it.

I can keep track of the Controller's `didDeactivate()` event, but then I have no idea if it was because the user stopped using the watch, tapped the Map or just went somewhere else.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there is no method or event in WatchKit to determine if a user tapped on a `WKInterfaceMap`. The closest technique is to use `didDeactivate`, and you've enumerated the challenges with this approach.